# Anchor tag download doesn't work on mobile

Tags: android, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm creating a mobile app using Ionic Framework, AngularJs, and Html.  There's a page where a user needs to click on a `<div>` to download a wallpaper, when I'm trying to click the download it works when I'm on the web browser debug mode using the `ionic serve` but when I try to create the apk and test it in the mobile, it doesn't work.  I have the following code on my html:

```
<div class="dl-btn">
<a download="someFilename" href="img/download-wallpaper.jpg">
<img src="img/download.png" width="40%" height="auto" class="center">
</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add any error you see in console logs with the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it works in the browser and not on devide is because the browser just opens the href link in a new tab which asks you to download the file.
In a mobile app, you don't really have the concept of a *new tab* since it's not a full browser.

You will have to use the *file transfer plugin* to download the file to a path on the user's device.

Check out the following section of the link and report back:

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer#download

Comment: but this one requires the file to be on the cloud right? this is what I did to my previous project. hmm I'm wondering if there's a way to get an image that is included in the apk. but for my question you answered it, so i'll mark this as answer in 2mins,

Comment: Thanks! I have not done what you really want but I guess you could try to use [this plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugins/tree/master/local-webserver) which would serve your _www_ in a localhost server _inside your app_ wherefrom you could then download the image file using the [file transfer plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer#download)

Comment: yeah but you answered my question with correct info and additional reference. but what i'm trying to do now is I uploaded the file from dropbox and share the file, just finding a way to download it throught the mobile. :D thanks btw